# I how to check for authenticated user and show then show a different content in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

What am trying to do is have two different user locations. One is from my user model and the other is default from view. I want that anytime a user is authenticated, the location from the model shows but if not logged in the default location should be passed to the view.

Views.py

```
class Home(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "Home.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Home, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if User.is_authenticated:
            map_location = self.request.user.location_on_the_map
        else:
            map_location = Point(longitude, latitude, srid=4326)
            
            context.update({
                'job_listing': JobListing.objects.annotate(
                    distance=Distance("location_on_the_map", map_location)
                ).order_by("distance")[0:6]
            })
        return context
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this `User.is_authenticated` to `self.request.user.is_authenticated`

Comment: works but the problem is the `else` is not working when user is not login. I want the else statement to replace if the user is not login @Reza Heydari

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the line User.is_authenticated to self.request.user.is_authenticated to ensure you are referencing the current user.

Alternatively you can add a request parameter on your function thus, you can use request.user.is_authenticated instead like so:

```
class Home(generic.TemplateView):
template_name = "Home.html"

def get_context_data(self, request, **kwargs):
    context = super(Home, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        map_location = self.request.user.location_on_the_map
    else:
        map_location = Point(longitude, latitude, srid=4326)
        
        context.update({
            'job_listing': JobListing.objects.annotate(
                distance=Distance("location_on_the_map", map_location)
            ).order_by("distance")[0:6]
        })
    return context
```

Comment: works but the problem is the `else` is not working when user is not login. I want the else statement to replace if the user is not login @Kevin Omyonga